# How to do deep copy of inner objects from Hibernate Entity to DTO?

Tags: java, spring-bean, apache-commons-beanutils

I have entity class

```
public Class StudentEntity{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private AddressEntity address;
    private ProfileEntity profile;
    //getter setter
}

public Class StudentDTO{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private AddressDTO address;
    private ProfileDTO profile;
    //getter setter
}
```

when I use `BeanUtils.copyProperties();` (from spring/apache common) it copies the `id` and `name` alone. How to copy the `address` and `profile` also?

If custom util has to be written, could you please share the snippet?

Comment: You can use [mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org)

Comment: What about writing a copy constructor for the classes of address and profile?

Comment: If you have a lot of this cases, you could consider using a library like ModelMapper.

Answer (score 2):

*BeanUtils*, *cloning* OR *serialization* would not work here as the inner data types are different. I would suggest you to set the fields of StudentDTO manually. You could use ***conversion constructor*** for AddressDTO and ProfileDTO. Copy constructor is the legal name, but since we are converting type also, better name would be a conversion constructor instead.

An example of conversion constructor in JDK is `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` , i.e. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection- which generates an ArrayList from any Collection object and copy all items from Collection object to newly created ArrayList object.

Example:

```
StudentEntity studentEntityObj = new StudentEntity();
studentEntityObj.setId(1);
studentEntityObj.setName("myStudent");
AddressEntity addressEntityObj = new AddressEntity();
addressEntityObj.setCity("myCity");
studentEntityObj.setAddress(addressEntityObj);
// All above lines would be taken care of already (i.e. data is filled from DB)

StudentDTO studentDTOObj = new StudentDTO();
// Call conversion constructor  
AddressDTO addressDtoObj = new AddressDTO(addressEntityObj);
studentDTOObj.setAddress(addressDtoObj);
studentDTOObj.setId(studentEntityObj.getId());
studentDTOObj.setName(studentEntityObj.getName());
System.out.println(studentDTOObj.toString());
```

where AddressDTO (OR ProfileDTO for that matter) including a conversion constructor looks like:

```
public class AddressDTO {

    private String city;

    // Conversion constructor  
    public AddressDTO(AddressEntity a) {
        this.city = a.getCity();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AddressDTO [city=" + getCity() + "]";
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

prints

`StudentDTO [id=1, name=myStudent, address=AddressDTO [city=myCity]]`

Comment: I agree on not using a reflection-based library.

Comment: I've not used conversion constructor. Could you please share the sample snippet for this given requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use SerializationUtils.clone(). This method deep clone your object. But you should mark your objects as Serializable.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html#clone(T)

Comment: I tried like `StudentDTO student = SerializationUtils.clone(studentEntity);` but it says to change the return type as `StudentEntity`

Comment: yeah, you are right. I understand your question wrong. If your want copy data from one class object to another class object - you should write your own code. Copy construcror or some kind of mapper.